# Find out whether response.write(body) has went to the url or not

Tags: node.js

I am developing a rest api using nodejs and request npm package.

It seems that my node server becomes idle after executing following line

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(body));
```

So i want to know that whether my post request has actually hit the url and waiting for response or its just idle because of some thing else.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly [end](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback) the response:

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(body));
response.end();

// which can be shortened to:
response.end(JSON.stringify(body));
```

Comment: Yes. I did that. I ended response explicitly. But dont see any activity beyond response.end(). I had also put console.log to find the flow.

Comment: So your client (which is?) keeps on waiting for the response, but it never gets it?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure whether its waiting or it has stuck somewhere else. thats what i want to find out. whether my client has made a call to the server to get data or not.